# Adding data to an existing XML file in IsolatedStorage using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I'm making an attendance app for teachers as a school project and I'm having problems with updating the xml file in isolated storage. I'm parsing the names of the students to a listbox from a custom xml file using LINQ to XML. Each listbox item has a checkbox and the name of the student. I then store the selected students to IsolatedStorage along with the current date using XmlSerializer. When I retrieve the stored xml file everything seems to be working but when I want to add more students, it just overwrites the previously stored file and doesn't add to it. How can I fix this bug so that it adds to the existing xml file instead of overwriting it?

Here are my save and load classes:

- Saving the Date and Names to IsolatedStorage: http://pastebin.com/2hjmna0a
- Loading Dates to a List: http://pastebin.com/r7sv77C0
- Loading Names to a List: http://pastebin.com/jLBVyjFS

I appreciate all the help you can give me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not on my dev machine to give you an example, but assuming your serialised file is a list of students, try the following methodology.

1) Deserialise the file you already have back into a list of objects.
 2) Add the students to the deserialised list.
      eg `MyList.Add(new Student { Name = "Charlie Smith" });`
      or `MyList.AddRange(MyListOfNewStudentsToAdd)`
 3) Serialise the whole list (with newly added data) back to the file.

That should work.

Comment: thanks man for replying! I decided that it didn't really matter if it overwrited the file or not. I used serialization instead of loading the file using the IsolatedStorageSettings and it worked out just fine. But thank you very much for trying to help me!